# Custom CMS working in Xampp and not in vagrant (include error)

Tags: php, xampp, vagrant

Ok following issue I am having and I will try to give as much info as possible.

I have written a custom cms for learning purposses.

As develop environment I used vagrant with a precission32 box. ( situation 1)

For reasons not important I temporarly worked with Xampp. ( situation 2)

This last week I created a vagrant environment (ubuntu trysty 64) again to work with. (situation 3)

> **How it's built.**
>
> or situation 1 I can't recall how it has been built up.
>
> situation 2 (xampp):
>
> > PHP 5.6.15 Apache 2.4.17 Standard ( for Xampp) apache modules enabled
>
> situation 3 (vagrant)
>
> > PHP 5.5.9 Apache 2.4.7 All apache modules installed as it is in xampp

**The problem**

> In situation 1 everything worked just fine
>
> In situation 2 everything is working just fine. No problems
>
> In situation 3 I get an fatal error on an include

**The following errors I get:**

```
Warning: include(libs/DKW\Tracking\Logged.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /vagrant/DKW-fms/index.php on line 40

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'libs/DKW\Tracking\Logged.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /vagrant/DKW-fms/index.php on line 40

Fatal error: Class 'DKW\Tracking\Logged' not found in /vagrant/DKW-fms/public/main/template/nav.php on line 2
```

The logged.php file does exist

Line 40 in index.php

```
 /**
  * Load classes from libs
 */
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {include LIBS. $class.".php";});
```

LIBS is defined in a different file.

```
define ('LIBS','libs/');
```

So now for the fatal error:

Line 2 in nav.php:

```
$this->logged = new DKW\Tracking\Logged();
```

The above codes were built in situation 1 and worked fine.
During the other situations, as far as I know, nothing has been changed that could cause these problems.

I can´t figure out what is wrong. Especially because in Xampp there is absolutely no problem.
Same files are used because in both environments the path is directed to the same folder.

Hopefully somebody can give me a pointer to where to look because I don´t see it anymore.

Edit:

Because I'm having second thoughts about the rights on my folder structure I have added my virtualhost file. Maybe something is wrong in this that causes this problem.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        ServerName dkwfms.com
        ServerAlias dev.dkwfms.com

        DocumentRoot /vagrant/DKW-fms
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride FileInfo
        </Directory>

        <Directory /vagrant/DKW-fms>
                Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
                AllowOverride FileInfo
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        loglevel warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_dkw-fms.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_dkw-fms.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

In the errors I noticed the trailing slashes in my include part.
On faceboook Elmar also pointed me to those trailing slashes.
For this I had to rewrite my autoload_register.

If anybody faces this problem as well I did the following

My class folder is defined in another file (this is not needed for the solution)

```
define ('LIBS','libs/');
```

Now for the autoloader:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($className)
{
    $namespace=str_replace("\\","/",__NAMESPACE__);
    $className=str_replace("\\","/",$className);
    $class=LIBS . (empty($namespace)?"":$namespace."/")."{$className}.php";
    include_once($class);
});
```

Lets hope this will help others to.

Comment: More generally, you can find solution to this kind of problem by following the steps here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the XAMPP stack runs on a Windows machine and the vagrant machine is UNIX.

You should check if the filename matches the class. 
Meaning that 'Logged' should direct to 'Logged.php' and not to 'logged.php' as a Unix file system is case sensitive.

Regards,

Comment: Tripple checked this. I am aware that this is a common problem when switching between windows and unix. I always to try keep it in mind when writting but it is still a human thing to make these mistakes.